# How to save a string array in realm (Swift)

Tags: ios, realm

Can anyone suggest how i can save a String array (which comes from the server) to Realm to display the received data in a tableView?

```
// Model
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class MessageModel: Object, Decodable {
    @objc dynamic var result: [String]
}
```

How to convert the data variable so that Realm can work with it. As far as I know, Realm does not work directly with String.

```
// ViewController
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

final class StartController: UIViewController {
 var data: [String] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setUpView()
        setUpConstraints()
        configData()
    }

    private func configData() {
        service.addMessage(offset: offsetStart) { [weak self] result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let dataMessage):
                self?.data = dataMessage
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self?.messageTable.reloadData()
                }
            case.failure(let error):
                print(error)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self?.showAlert(title: "Error", message: "Error connecting to the server")
                }
            }
        }
    }

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = messageTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath)
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "backgroundColor")
        let messageList = data[indexPath.row]
        var content = cell.defaultContentConfiguration()
        content.text = messageList
        return cell
    }
}
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `List` for saving an array of strings in Realm. Check the following post for more information [Realm with primitive types](https://academy.realm.io/posts/realm-list-new-superpowers-array-primitives/)